# Need to Pick Max Date when status = N otherwise No in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max, exists, date-formatting

I have  a  table which have  records like  this

```
   ID           DATEADD        STATUS
'A0011'  '04/01/2018 11:58:31'  'C'
'A0011'  '31/05/2019 10:02:36'  'N'
'B0022'  '04/01/2018 11:58:31'  'N'
'B0022'  '31/05/2019 10:02:36'  'N'
'B0022'  '30/04/2020 19:44:36'  'C'
'C0033'  '04/01/2018 11:58:31'  'N'
'C0033'  '30/05/2019 06:02:36'  'C'
'C0033'  '29/04/2020 05:44:36'  'C'
```

I'm trying to get the  Max Date for  each ID  which have STATUS = 'N'. If I get MAX DATE and STATUS = 'C' then I don't want that record.

Output  :

```
   ID           DATEADD        STATUS
'A0011'  '31/05/2019 10:02:36'  'N'
```

SCRIPT :

```
SELECT I.* FROM INVOICE I
INNER JOIN (
Select ID,MAX(DATEADD)DATEADD,STATUS FROM INVOICE WHERE STATUS = 'N'
GROUP BY ID,STATUS) O
ON I.ID = O.ID AND O.DATEADD = I.DATEADD
```

But I'm not able to get desired output.

Comment: `O.DATEADD` doesn't show you the expected value?

Comment: What is the data type of DATEADD?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to give you a downvote for posting a query that is not actually the one you need help with. That's kind of disrespectful of people's time, and given your reputation score I know you are not a new user, so you should know better.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have mentioned  that I have written the query same like  you to handle the dates  but it is not  giving accurate result. What is disrespectful in that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT i1.* 
FROM INVOICE i1
WHERE i1.STATUS = 'N'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INVOICE i2
    WHERE i2.ID = i1.ID 
      AND STR_TO_DATE(i2.DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') > STR_TO_DATE(i1.DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
  );
```

If the column's `DATEADD` data type is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` the last condition would be simpler:

```
...AND i2.DATEADD > i1.DATEADD
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4b47859c0c5232f14619b01f16e4a92).

Comment: Let me  try in my code and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql version support the window function, we can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get each `ID` latest `DATEADD` then compare the `STATUS`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATEADD DESC) rn
 FROM INVOICE
) t1
WHERE rn = 1 AND STATUS = 'N'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4471c171eadfb7262d444449f6c0ba6f)

if your MySQL version didn't support the window function we can try to use correlated subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM INVOICE tt 
            WHERE tt.ID = t1.ID AND tt.DATEADD > t1.DATEADD) rn
 FROM INVOICE t1
) t1
WHERE rn = 1 AND STATUS = 'N'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=755e6af1ac0950526121e0602a07b2f6)

Comment: I'm looking  for  MYSQL and older version 5.7.32 and it won't support Row_number

Comment: @mohan111 Ok I see I edited my answer you can try this.

Comment: let's  try from my side

Comment: str_to_date(tt.DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %T' ) > str_to_date(t1.DATEADD, '%d/%m/%Y %T' )) When I add this  condition in Sub query it is  giving  error as Unknown column

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1` to get the row that we want without using any functions, sub-queries, CTE etc.
Thank you to D-Shih for the test schema.
If we want the maximum date with status 'N' for each ID we can use the second query.

> ```
> SELECT
>   ID,
>   DATEADD,
>   STATUS
> FROM INVOICE
> ORDER BY 
>   STATUS DESC,
>   DATEADD DESC
> LIMIT 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID    | DATEADD    | STATUS
> :---- | :--------- | :-----
> A0011 | 2019-05-31 | N
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   ID,
>   MAX(DATEADD) AS DATEADD,
>   STATUS
> FROM INVOICE
> WHERE STATUS = 'N'
> GROUP BY ID
> ORDER BY ID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID    | DATEADD    | STATUS
> :---- | :--------- | :-----
> A0011 | 2019-05-31 | N     
> B0022 | 2019-05-31 | N     
> C0033 | 2018-01-04 | N
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=955b603e74819f5abe4be3b940a40752)*

Comment: But I think OP want to get that for each ID `I'm trying to get the Max Date for each ID`, LIMIT 1 might only get one row

Comment: @D-Shih - I think that you're right - the desciption and the required output don't tell the same story.